# Trying to pass $_POST variables onto another page (Using GAE for deployment)

Tags: php

I am working with multiple forms on a page, where pressing a button will edit that specific post (using the hidden input variable).

I am dealing with two issues here:

1. When I do press edit, it will grab the **last** hash from the list (I am using a foreach loop to iterate through the list).
2. When I do press edit and redirect to the next page, the $_POST variable is deemed null.

Page 1:

```php
foreach ($result as $item) {
            echo '  
                    <form method="post" action="editPost">
                        <input type="hidden" id="messageID" value="' . $messageID . '">
                        # Print $item iterations here in the form of a html form
                        <div>
                            <input type="submit" value="Edit" name="editPost">
                        </div>
                    </form>
            ';
}
```

Page 2:

```php
if ($_POST['messageID'] == null) {
    echo '<script>alert("Key error")</script>';
} else {
    # Do things if $_POST['messageID'] is not null
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should not add Form inside the loop and input or form with same id or name in loop will confuse html to what should send and may it will send last one,

instead of form in loop just add link of other page with edit record id or hash as in query string
`example.com/pagetwo.php?editid=$messageid`

and from page 2 you can get that variable useing
`$_GET['editid'] or $_REQUEST['editid']`
and based on id you need to get data from database and fill in inputs to update it

Comment: Does this work with google app engine? Because especially with php74, we have to set up a YAML page in order to do this. (link: https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/php7/runtime#php-7.4). So I don't know if I am approaching this right then